# How to generate an average in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have two counters.  One is a measurement accumulator and another is the count of measurements.  How do I generate a range vector average?

I've tried the following but got null results.

```
rate(my_events{type="sum"}[60s]) / rate(my_events{type="count"}[60s])
```

I want to generate a vector that I can put into a Grafana graph to plot the average over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're onto the right idea, what you'd do is:

`rate(my_events{type="sum"}[60s]) / ignoring(type) rate(my_events{type="count"}[60s])`

However the canonical way of exporting and thus using this data is:

`rate(my_events_sum[60s]) / rate(my_events_count[60s])`

Which you can do with a Summary or Histogram.

Comment: Awesome!  After re-reading the documentation it makes perfect sense.